# Importing data into Excel from a Access DB with a linked table

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am trying to import data from an Access table into an Excel sheet. Unfortunately, the table in Access is linked, and apparently Excel doesn't like that. It just tells me that no tables are present. For complicated reasons that are not really relevant to the problem, I can't go to the original data source, I have to go through this linked table. Does anyone know of any workarounds for this? Thank you.

Comment: you can create a query in Access using that file, select the fields that you need and then you can connect this query to Excel.

Comment: *It just tells me that no tables are present* ... what tells you this? Please describe specific steps. What is the source of linked table: server RBDMS? Another Access file?

Comment: To answer your question, I was importing to an Excel file from an Access database, as stated in my original question. The "no tables present" was a message I got from a pop up dialogue box in Excel. I found that using the New Query>From Database option in the Data tab solved my problem. Why Excel will recognize the existence of the linked table when using that method but not when using Get External Data is anyone's guess. I'm just glad it worked.